# Perform function if user thumb is on image - Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am developing `Windows Phone 8.1` application (`XAML`, `C#`). In my UI, I have a image control. When the user taps on this image, I want to display a gif in place of that image until user pull off his finger from that image.

So, If user finger is on that image for 15 seconds, that gif will be displayed for 15 seconds.

I can not find any useful functionality on internet for this kind of issue.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use MouseLeftButtonDown and MouseLeftButtonUp events in Image control.

```
private void Image_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
     Image.Source = //Source of GIF image
}

private void Image_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
     Image.Source = //Source of original image
}
```

When you place your finger over the image the MouseLeftButtonDown event will be fired and once you leave the finger the MouseLeftButtonUp event will be fired.

Comment: There is no MouseLeftButtonUp event for Image in Windows Phone 8.1.